# How to get Upper HTML Tag with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I trying to a class to my html page with jquery, here is my code.

```
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="itmId">1</td>
    <td class="entryNAmee">David</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="itmId">2</td>
    <td class="entryNamee">Alan</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am changing the td to input text with jquery on clicking in the every td except 1st column. that is working fine and when the above event perform the tr become like below.

```
    <tr>
      <td class="itmId">1</td>
      <td class="entryNAmee nowText">
        <input type="text" value="Alan">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

After making corrections an event working in blur. code is below.

js.

```
$(document).on('blur','table tr td input',function()
{   
    var fieldNewValue = $(this).val();
    var fieldNewId = $(this).closest('td.itmId').addClass("kkkkkkkkk");
    //console.log(fieldNewId);
    alert(fieldNewId);
    /*$.ajax({
        typr:"post",
        url:"updateEntry",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{newValue:fieldNewValue},
        success:function(data)
        {
            console.log("updated succesfully");
        }
    });
    */
    $(this).parents('td').text(fieldNewValue).removeClass('nowText');
    $(this).remove();

});
```

I Want to add a class to the upper td of the the clicked td.
I tried the closest and parents jquery api's, But didnt work,

Anyone can please support me to how to catch the td ?

Also what are the different between closest and parents in jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
var fieldNewId = $(this).closest('td.itmId').addClass("kkkkkkkkk");
```

to:

```
var fieldNewId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.itmId').addClass("kkkkkkkkk");
```

You can read the docs to see the differences between [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), however in your code you weren't traversing far enough up the DOM. `$(this).closest('td.itmId')` was looking for a td that didn't exist where you expected it to since it's a sibling of the parent cell that you were in.

You could also use `(this).closest('td').prev()` instead of `(this).closest('tr').find('td.itmId')`

Answer (score 1):

There is also [.prev in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) which returns the "upper" or better previous element in current context. It works just like this:

```
$(this).prev().addClass('kkkkkkkkk')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "previous sibling" of the input tag.

Comment: Drakes, ah true.. I thought it was needed for td:s only